# Google Cloud SQL storage size doesn't change

Tags: google-cloud-sql

We are now testing the system. I have created an instance with 30 GB storage and added 20 GB data. After a while i have deleted my current database and created it again. I couldn't complete the transfer because of storage space. It seems that after i delete data, system didn't release the disk space. I had to allocate 50 GB data to complete. After i upload data i deleted the biggest table and again system didn't release the storage space.

What do i have to do now? Also is it possible to assign a static ip to our DB?

Comment: Do you have binary logs enabled?

Comment: Yes they are enabled

Comment: I have tried disabling but it didn't help. Also i have backups and i want to delete them too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When binary logs are enabled, MySQL records all database changes to a log file for the purposes of replication and point-in-time recovery.

Deleting a table does not affect the size of the existing binary log (the table deletion is recorded in the binary log).

You can try disabling the binary log which should cause the existing logs to be pruned.

Consider disabling the binary log before performing large imports for a new instance if you wish to conserve disk space (and don't care about replication or point-in-time recovery). You can re-enable it after the import is complete.

The instance should have a static IP assigned from creation, you don't need to take any actions.

Comment: This helps. Thank you so much. What do i have to use for archive data? For example i have 30 GB data but i don't want to keep it in mysql. It costs a lot.

Comment: 30GB is about $5/month for the Cloud SQL storage costs. If you don't need online access to the data, you could write a script to archive old data to Cloud Storage (or some other storage system) and load it only when necessary. I think on Cloud Storage, 30GB would cost less than $1/month.

Comment: can you please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34819280/can-not-connect-to-google-sql